# When using .load() to insert an html file, javascript doesn't recognize elements and returns null

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, load

I'm using a .load() method to insert an HTML file into my pages which inclues SVG information. However when I try to access the elements in the imported SVG file I get `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"`

This is the index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Party Packs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c761a1adc3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="insert-here"></div>

  <script src="js/anime.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And then this is the SVG file I'm trying to import

```
<svg id="transmorph" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path class="transmorph" d="M1920 0V1C1547.5 -118 1557 5 1450.5 1C1344 -3 1307 1 1224.5 1C1142 1 1105 1 899.5 1C693.414 1 698.5 1 567 1C421.424 1 345 -11.5 222 1C123.6 11 162 -12 0 1V0H1920Z" fill="#1a1a1a" />
</svg>
```

The index.js contains:

```
$(function() {
  $('#transition-main-div').load('morph.html');
  console.log(document.querySelector('#insert-here'));
});
```

If I try `console.log('#insert-here');` in the index.js file it just returns null. I've searched all over the internet and all I can find is instances where people put script before the html content has loaded but unless I'm missing something, that's not the case here.
Thanks.

Comment: I might be missing something but there's no element with `id="transition-main-div"` I can see anywhere? Also the async issue. And `console.log(document.querySelector('#insert-here'));` works perfectly fine for me, it logs the `<div>` as expected. And `console.log('#insert-here');` returns null, but outputs `#insert-here`, also as expected. It's just a String, and console.log() produces no return value.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the code you provided, in addition to the callback/async issue, you need `$('#insert-here').load('morph.html');` and `console.log(document.querySelector('#transmorph'));` in the callback. This seems to be a "I haven't had any coffee yet" issue more than anything else ;)

Answer (score 1):

`load` is asynchronous. You've searching the DOM for its result before it has received the response and added it to the DOM. You need to pass a callback, as per the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#transition-main-div').load('morph.html', function () {
    console.log(document.querySelector('#insert-here'));
});
```